# Which is the most appropriate book I should acquire in order to get started with selenium webdriver + jbehave?

Tags: selenium

We need to test a web application coded in html and javascript. They decided to use Selenium webdriver + jbehave technology and I am not very familiar with it.

Which is the most appropriate book I should acquire in order to get started with selenium webdriver + jbehave?

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend this book about selenium: https://leanpub.com/LearningSelenium. This will quickly bring you up to speed with Selenium and Webdriver. Next you should read a book about Java, any book about the fundamentals of Java will do. When finished reading I think you should think about new questions to ask :-)

good luck

[Addendum]
The most valuable about the book is that it covers selenium IDE and then slowly moves to more advanced topics like locators with Xpath etc. Next is setting up a project in Eclipse IDE and build your own framework. This gently introduces java programming language because everything is explained in detail.
After that the writer moves on to give a small introduction to page objects and measuring performance.

So if you really want to use Java framework Jbehave together with Selenium this *cheap* book give a good intro into selenium/java for beginners.

I have to mention that not all chapters are finished but I believe you are entitled to free updates.

Comment: Hi, @mjvdende, and welcome. Could you give a bit more information about what you find most valuable about the book you referenced?

Comment: excellent information. Thank you for the updates.

Answer (score 0):

[**Selenium WebDriver Practical Guide**](http://amzn.to/29j6D9j)

Creating automation test scripts for your web applications with Selenium WebDriver has never

been easier thanks to this user-friendly book. All you need is a basic knowledge of Core

Java, and then the practical tutorials supply the rest.

About This Book

Covers basic to advanced concepts of WebDriver
Learn how to design a more effective automation framework
Explores all of the APIs within WebDriver
Acquire an in-depth understanding of each concept through practical code examples

Who This Book Is For

If you are a quality assurance/testing professional, a software developer, or a web

application developer looking to create automation test scripts for your web applications,

this is the perfect guide for you! As a prerequisite, a basic knowledge of Core Java is

expected, although any previous knowledge of WebDriver or Selenium 1 is not needed.

What You Will Learn

Learn the basic design of Selenium WebDriver and understand how it overcomes the limitations

of its predecessor
Set up and use Selenium Grid
Discover the various mechanisms used to locate web elements
Perform advanced actions such as drag-and-drop, double-click, right-click, and action

builders on web pages
Explore the advanced features of WebDriver such as handling cookies, taking

screenshotsmanaging timeouts, and browser navigations
Acquire an understanding of the various WebDriver implementations such as Firefox Driver, IE

Driver, and Chrome Driver
Explore WebDriver EventListeners
Design effective automation frameworks using the PageObject pattern
Learn how to deal with the latest features of WebDriver

---

[**Selenium Testing Tools Cookbook**](http://amzn.to/29j6tyI)

Unlock the full potential of Selenium WebDriver to test your web applications in a wide range

of situations. The countless recipes and code examples provided ease the learning curve and

provide insights into virtually every eventuality.

About This Book

Learn to leverage the power of Selenium WebDriver with simple examples that illustrate real

world problems and their workarounds
Each sample demonstrates key concepts allowing you to advance your knowledge of Selenium

WebDriver in a practical and incremental way
Explains testing of mobile web applications with Selenium Drivers for platforms such as iOS

and Android

Who This Book Is For

This book is intended for software quality assurance/testing professionals, software project

managers, or software developers with prior experience in using Selenium and Java for testing

web-based applications. This book also provides examples for C#, Python, and Ruby users.

What You Will Learn

Understand Locators and use various locator methods to build reliable tests
Build reliable and maintainable tests with Selenium WebDriver API
Use PageFactory Pattern to build a robust and easy- to-maintain test framework
Build data driven tests and extend Selenium API to implement custom steps and checks
Learn to integrate and use ATDD/BDD tools such as JBehave, SpecFlow, and FitNesses with

Selenium WebDriver
Set up iPhone/iPad & Android simulators and devices for testing your mobile web application
Set up Selenium Grid for faster and parallel run of tests, increasing test coverage and

reducing test execution time
Capture screenshots and videos of test runs